# ASP.NET Core API Endpoint which delivers a Stream instead of big JSONArray

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, stream

I have a pretty big list of objects, which needs to be received fast from the client. Currently it takes about 2-4 seconds. I now try to use streams to send chunks (e.g. 100 objects in each) I know that GRPC can use streams but in ASP.NET core, how can I achieve this? The normal ASP.NET has `PushStreamContent` which is not available in Core. Any solutions out there? I can't really find a proper one online.

So what my Controller currently looks like:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Price>>> GetPrices()
 {
     return await _context.Prices.ToListAsync();
 }
```

This list currently contains around 18700 Items but this number will increase by time.

Comment: To make sure here... "received fast from the client" - does that mean you want to handle the response with a stream or the request?

Comment: "Currently it takes about 2-4 seconds" - if you already have some working code it makes it much easier to answer the question if you can provide this for us. Take a look at [ask]

Comment: I now extended the question with an example @Xerillio . 
I actually want to be able to quickly load this huge JSON from the client. Maybe I dont need any handling on server side, just receive as stream on client side then?

And - is it a code smell / bad practice to send such big JSON data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using EF Core based on your example.

If you take a look at [Efficient Querying - Buffering and streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-querying#buffering-and-streaming), they recommend using `AsEnumerable` to stream the data instead of `ToList`, which essentially loads all data into memory before (in your case) returning it to the client. The async version is `AsAsyncEnumerable`.

So you should be able to simply change your controller action into:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Price>>> GetPrices()
{
    return await _context.Prices.AsAsyncEnumerable();
}
```

Note, that streaming rather than buffering/loading into memory does not mean performance improvements in all cases, but with a large dataset there's a good chance you'll see better performance.

> is it a code smell / bad practice to send such big JSON data?

Not necessarily. If you actually need to have the entire dataset client-side, then this is probably the most efficient approach. However, if your dataset is large, you should expect that it takes some time to download. If your download speed is 5 MB/s and your `Price` data is 10 MB, then you'll never make it faster than 2 seconds without a better connection. Even if you use a stream from your backend.

Another approach (if that fits your needs) is to introduce paging. That way you can retrieve e.g. 50 items at a time instead of everything and then page through it. But whether it makes sense to use paging from your client is up to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer, but what would the client code look like to receive the stream?

Comment: @totallynotatallno That depends on what you want to do with the data client-side. By default you don't need to do anything different. When making a request, the client will receive all the data in one go and you can display the list however you like. If you want to show the elements as they arrive, you'll need some streaming client-side. But it sounds a little complex if you're only talking about 2-4 seconds waiting time. If you have some requirements, I'll suggest creating a new question for it.